# Can database entries added from items be deleted with button?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to teach myself android development using "Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" and one of the exercises (from chapter 14 if you are familiar with the book) involves creating a toolbar with an item that adds new entries to the database when the item is clicked. A challenge question is deleting the entries, but I want to delete the entry from WITHIN the entry. Sorry if I am not doing a good job explaining this.

Basically when opening the app for the first time, there is a mostly empty display with a toolbar with two items in the top right. [Here is a screenshot if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWSW2.jpg). The two items add or count the number of entries, which are then displayed on the list. In the image above, there is one entry. When you click the + symbol, a new entry is added, and it takes you to the [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doASz.jpg) for the entry that lets you add all the details. I want to add a delete button that allows you to erase the entry while looking at the details.

Here is the code I tried but didn't work: 
In CrimeLab.java

```
public void addCrime(Crime c){
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(c);

    mDatabase.insert(CrimeTable.NAME, null, values);
}

public void deleteCrime(Crime crimeId){

    String uuidString = crimeId.toString();
    mDatabase.delete(CrimeTable.NAME, null, new String[] 
{uuidString});
}
```

I basically tried to undo what I did when creating a database entry.
In CrimeListFragment.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_item_new_crime:
            Crime crime = new Crime();
            CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).addCrime(crime);
            Intent intent = 
CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), crime.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_show_subtitle:
            mSubtitleVisible = !mSubtitleVisible;
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            updateSubtitle();
            return true;
        case R.id.delete_button:
            Crime mCrime = new Crime();
            CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).deleteCrime(mCrime);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I think I need to create an onClick action, but where would this go if I'm trying to delete entries from a database created by items from within the entry?

Something else I would like to add is deleting entries from the original page by sliding to reveal a delete button, like in messenger apps.

Sorry if I didn't properly ask my question. This is a whole new world for me and going along with the book is helpful, but I found its easy to think you understand something and then be completely lost on your own.
Also, I checked though stackoverflow and other various forums and did not find an exact answer to this question.

Per request, here is the code for Crime.java:

```
public class Crime {
    private String mTitle;
    private Date mDate;
    private boolean mSolved;
    private String mSuspect;

    public Date getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    private UUID mId;

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        mDate = date;
    }

    public void setSolved(boolean solved) {
        mSolved = solved;
    }

    public String getSuspect(){
        return mSuspect;
    }

    public  void setSuspect (String suspect){
        mSuspect = suspect;
    }

    public String getPhotoFilename(){
        return "IMG_" + getId().toString() + ".jpg";
    }

    public boolean isSolved() {

        return mSolved;
    }



    public Crime(){
        //generate unique identifier
        this(UUID.randomUUID());
    }

    public Crime(UUID id){
        mId = id;
        mDate = new Date();
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }
}
```

This is the .java class that controls my database entries:

```
public class CrimeBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "crimeBase.db";

    public CrimeBaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("create table " + CrimeTable.NAME + "(" +
                " _id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.TITLE + ", " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.DATE + ", " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.SOLVED + ", " +
                CrimeTable.Cols.SUSPECT +
                ")"
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

    }
}
```

This is where I am messing up the .onClickListener

```
mDeleteButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Crime mCrime = new crime();
                mCrime.getId()
                CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).deleteCrime(mCrime);
            }
                                         }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternative Answer

The following is the code for a pretty basic, but working example. However, it goes a little further by incorporating a **ListView** and allowing deletion by LongClicking an item in the **ListView**.

However, this doesn't use fragments.

There's 3 pieces of code, the **MainActivity** (`MainActivity.java`), The SQLiteOpenHelper subclass **CrimeDBHelper** (`CrimeDBHelper.java`) and the layout for the MainActivity, `activity_main.xml`:-

#### activity_main.xml

This is pretty straight-forward. Note that it includes a **ListView** at the end.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="The Crime Thing"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Crime Title"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crimetitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Crime Date"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crimedate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Suspect"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crimesuspect"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Crime Solved?"
        />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/crimesolved"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addcrime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ADD CRIME"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/dltcrime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DLT CRIME (ID=?)"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/crimelist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

#### CrimeDBHelper.java

Most is similar, except the additional method **`getCrimeList()`**, this returns a Cursor that contains all the data from the crimes table (used for populating the ListView).

```
public class CrimeDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "crimesdb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String CRIMESTABLE = "crimes";
    public static final String CRIMEID_COL = "_id";
    public static final String CRIMETITLE_COL = "crimetitle";
    public static final String CRIMEDATE_COL = "crimedate";
    public static final String CRIMESUSPECT_COL = "crimesuspect";
    public static final String CRIMESOLVED_COL = "crimesolved";


    public static final String TABLECRTSQL =
            "CREATE TABLE " + CRIMESTABLE + "(" +
                    CRIMEID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    CRIMETITLE_COL + " TEXT," +
                    CRIMEDATE_COL + " TEXT, " +
                    CRIMESUSPECT_COL + " TEXT, " +
                    CRIMESOLVED_COL + " INTEGER" +
                    ");";

    public CrimeDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLECRTSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
    }

    public long addCrime(String crimetitle, String crimedate, String crimesuspect, int crimesolved) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CRIMETITLE_COL,crimetitle);
        cv.put(CRIMEDATE_COL,crimedate);
        cv.put(CRIMESUSPECT_COL,crimesuspect);
        cv.put(CRIMESOLVED_COL,crimesolved);
        return db.insert(CRIMESTABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public int deleteCrime(long crimeid) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String whereclause = CRIMEID_COL + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = {Long.toString(crimeid)};
        return db.delete(CRIMESTABLE,whereclause,whereargs);
    }

    public Cursor getCrimeList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(CRIMESTABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mCrimeTitle;
    EditText mCrimeDate;
    EditText mCrimeSuspect;
    CheckBox mCrimeSolved;

    Button mAddCrime;
    Button mDltCrime;
    ListView mCrimeList;

    CrimeDBHelper dbhlpr = new CrimeDBHelper(this);
    Cursor crimelist;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;

    long lastcrimeid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCrimeTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.crimetitle);
        mCrimeDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.crimedate);
        mCrimeSuspect = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.crimesuspect);
        mCrimeSolved = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.crimesolved);
        mCrimeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.crimelist);
        mAddCrime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addcrime);
        mDltCrime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dltcrime);

        crimelist = dbhlpr.getCrimeList();

        // Setup Button to Add a crime
        mAddCrime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int solved = 0;
                if (mCrimeSolved.isChecked()) {
                    solved = 1;
                }
                lastcrimeid =  dbhlpr.addCrime(
                        mCrimeTitle.getText().toString(),
                        mCrimeDate.getText().toString(),
                        mCrimeSuspect.getText().toString(),
                        solved
                );
                mDltCrime.setText("DLT CRIME (ID=" + Long.toString(lastcrimeid) + ")");
                mDltCrime.setTag(lastcrimeid);
                crimelist = dbhlpr.getCrimeList();
                sca.swapCursor(crimelist);
            }
        });

        // Setup button to delete the latest Crime added
        mDltCrime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //dbhlpr.deleteCrime(lastcrimeid); can do it this way
                if (view.getTag() != null) {
                    dbhlpr.deleteCrime((long)view.getTag());
                    crimelist = dbhlpr.getCrimeList();
                    sca.swapCursor(crimelist);
                }
            }
        });

        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                crimelist,
                new String[]{CrimeDBHelper.CRIMETITLE_COL},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );
        mCrimeList.setAdapter(sca);

        mCrimeList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                dbhlpr.deleteCrime(l);
                crimelist = dbhlpr.getCrimeList();
                sca.swapCursor(crimelist);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (crimelist != null) {
            crimelist.close();
        }

    }
}
```

The first thing to note is the line `long lastcrimeid;`, this is declared at the class level so is very much available throughout (*the issue you were having with **`long databaseID`***).

You might also notice **`SimpleCursorAdapter sca;`** this will be used for the **`ListView`** (*basically it places the data from the cursor in the ListView*).

You should be familiar with much of the following code. In summray:-

- super.onCreate is called.
- The activity is set to use the activity_main.xml layout.
- As the layout has been loaded the id's associated with the views are obtained.
- A Cursor is obtained getting the current crimes from the database (may be none, this isn't a problem).
- the button listener for adding a crime is added. Note that this uses the returned **_id** of the added row twice (*actually 3 times as it changes the delete buttons text accordingly*).

  - **`lastcrimeid`** is set by the return of the `addCrime()` method.
  - `mDltCrime.setTag(lastcrimeid);` sets the tag of the  delete button to the **`_id`** of the added row.
  - Also note that two additional lines exist namely `crimelist = dbhlpr.getCrimeList();` and `sca.swapCursor(crimelist);`.

    - The first replaces the cursor with what is now in the database (i.e. includes the row that has been added), the second tells the ListView to use the new cursor, so causes the ListView to show what is now in the database (this is used again when deleting a row).
  - the button listener for the delete button is then added. This can work in two ways. The **`lastcrimeid`** can be used or alternately the button's tage can be used as both hold the **_id** of the row to be deleted. The code has the former commented out, so the latter method is used (i.e. the value in the button's tag is retrieved).

    - Note this latter method has the disadvantage that the value can be null, which would cause a null pointer exception, hence the `if (view.getTag != null)`.
  - As above for refreshing the **ListView**.
  - Next the SimpleCursorAdapter is setup, it takes 5 parameters:-

    - the layout to be used (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) is a stock layout.
    - the data to be used in the form of a Cursor. NOTE! a column named **_id** MUST exist (*generally a good idea to always use `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` for this reason.*) Note we get a Cursor **`crimelist`** via the `getCrimeList` method.
    - The column(s) in the cursor from which the data is to be retrieved.
    - The view(s) in the layout where the retrieved data will be placed.
    - A value which I can't recall the purpose of. However 0 is fine to use. Not coding this 5th parameter will likely result in deprecated message.
    - (Note I normally use Custom CursorAdapters as they are much more flexible, so rarely use Simples).
- Then the ListView is told to use the Adapter as per `mCrimeList.setAdapter(sca);`.
- Then an `onItemLongClickListener` is added to the ListView, which will delete the crime that was longclicked (long l is the **_id** value, hence a reason why a CursorAdapter needs **_id** and hence why `dbhlpr.deleteCrime(l);`).

  - Again the **ListView** is refreshed.
- Finally, as the cursor is used while the activity remains in use `onDestory` method is used to close the Cursor (Cursors should always be closed when finished with).

This is how it looks (not pretty but functional), with three Crimes added (The delete button would remove the *The Crime of the Century* crime). Long-Clicking any listed crime will delete that crime. Clicking add would add another entry for Crime of the Century unless the data were changed.

[image]

Comment: Just realized this answer was posted by you too.  Thank you so much for the help.  I'm going to build this in a completely new project and try to understand what's going on so I can hopefully implement it in my project.  I'm not against using listview, and it seems like it might even be the better fit for what I'm doing.  I was just following along with my book using fragments.  I might end up completely redoing everything in this format!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `mDatabase.delete(CrimeTable.NAME, null, new String[] 
{uuidString});` is incorrect.

The 2nd parameter should be the selection criteria or **where clause** (less the WHERE keyword)
e.g. `yourtablecolumn = yourvalue`.

The 3rd parameter can be used in conjunction with the 2nd. The 2nd can have a placeholder **?** (*or a number of place holders for more complex selection criteria*). So in your example it would be along the lines of :-

```
String whereclause = "mycolumn=?";
mDatabase.delete(CrimeTable.NAME,whereclause, new String[]{uuidString});
```

*Obviously **`mycolumn`** would be replaced with the actual column name.*

You may find this useful [SQLiteDatabase - delete](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29)

### Additional Issues

Additionally you have:-

```
        case R.id.delete_button:
            Crime mCrime = new Crime();
            CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).deleteCrime(mCrime);
```

Does the constructor for a Crime object, get all the data from the database, it may be that mCrime is basically void of any real usable data (unable to tell with the information provided, so perhaps include the complete Crime class code).

Furthermore crimeDelete, expects and gets a Crime object, which you name as crimeid, this will very likely NOT be the id of the entry in the Crimetable, rather it is the Crimeobject converted to a string.

It is very likely that you

a) need to set the appropriate values of the Crime object after `Crime mCrime = new Crime();`

and then

b) get the appropriate crimeid value from the crimeid in the 'deleteCrime' method. I'd suggest not calling the crime crimeid but instead use something more descriptive.

Assuming that your Crime class has a a member mID which holds the unique identifier according to what is held in the CrimeTable then something along the lines of:-

```
case R.id.delete_button
    Crime mCrime = new crime();
    mCrime.setID(ID_obtained_from_displayed_crime);
    CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).deleteCrime(mCrime);


public void deleteCrime(Crime crime){

    mDatabase.delete(CrimeTable.NAME, "IDCOLUMN=?", new String[] 
{crime.getID()});
}
```

This assumes methods `setID()` and `String getID()` in the Crime Class and that `IDCOLUMN` is the column (assuming one exists) that is used for the unqiue identifier e.g. it will be defined as `columnname INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `columnname INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` (ps the latter is not advised as it is very likely not needed and it has overheads).

### Addition after the inclusion of Crime.java and of the DBHelper

`Crime mCrime = new crime();`

Will construct an object called mCrime that has a randomly generated UUID which will likely NOT be a UUID stored in the database and even more unlikely be the the UUID of the Crime to be deleted.

As you already have `_id integer primary key autoincrement,` (PS AUTOINCREMENT is best removed as per [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) , but not an issue) then there is little if any need for UUID as you will rely upon what's in the database so the **`_id`** column is ideal.

When you insert it returns the **id** of the inserted row so you can easily get this using:-

```
public long addCrime(Crime c){
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(c);
    return mDatabase.insert(CrimeTable.NAME, null, values);
}
```

So you could then:-

- at the start of the fragment/activity code `long MyCrimeID;`
- change `CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).addCrime(crime);`

  - to `myCrimeID = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).addCrime(crime);`

Note! id will always be 1 or greater, 0 means not inserted (shouldn't happen as only _id column needs to be unique according to your table definition).

I'd suggest changing `crimeDelete` to be passed a long e.g. it could be:-

```
public int deleteCrime(long id){
    String whereclause = "-id=?";
    String[] whereargs = {Long.toString(id)};
    return mDatabase.delete(CrimeTable.NAME, whereclause, whereargs);
}
```

You will notice that it returns an integer, this is the number of rows affected. 0 = nothing deleted, you expect it to be 1. So you can now check to see if anything was deleted.

So you could then do :-

```
CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).deleteCrime(myCrimeID);
```

*Note! if you do alter the structure of the table, you will need to delete the App's data as `onCreate` only gets called automatically when the database file doesn't exist.*

This assumes a very basic scenario, you can only delete what you just added.

### As per the comment here's some code that will allow you to see what's in the table:-

```
    public void showAll(String table) {
        Cursor csr = mDatabase.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        String rowinfo;
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rowinfo = "Row " + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition()) + " has:-";
            for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                rowinfo = rowinfo + "\n\t Column Name=" +
                        csr.getColumnName(i) +
                        " with a value of " +
                        csr.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("SHOWALL",rowinfo);
        }
    }
```

Invoke this, at suitable points, using

```
CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).showALL(CrimeTable.NAME);
```

This will then add lines to the log along the lines of :-

```
08-17 09:55:46.073 2310-2310/mjt.cardoniser D/SHOWALL: Row 0 has:-
                                                         Column Name=_id with a value of 2
                                                         Column Name=username with a value of NotMikeatAll
                                                         Column Name=userhash with a value of DZQGvy0a9l0M/kmpmDlR8Q==

                                                         Column Name=usersalt with a value of YaqqUZVgOO6OOG4cnAyQndipcEw6YWNAV5DvJKl8gRA=

                                                         Column Name=userflags with a value of 0
```

*The above, also gives a little bit of an insight into using a **Cursor** for extracting/accessing the data from the database.*

Comment: I tried changing the "null" to all of the column values being deleted, so I called mDatabase.delete five time, once for each column, with a different column.  The result was the same, the button still had no effect.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Odds on, assuming that crimeDelete is being called/invoked, is that uuidString is not a match for a value. So 1st confirm that crimeDelete is actually being invoked and then, if so, that uuisString holds a suitable value. Adding a breakpoint at `mDatabase.delete(......` and then running in debug mode, would allow you to do both.

Comment: I added this code to my main class file:         mDeleteButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).deleteCrime(mCrime);
            }
                                         }
        ); Now I'm sure that the process is getting invoked, but it's causing my app to crash instead of deleting the entry.  Any thoughts?  Thanks again

Comment: @KyleG see updated answer, there are other issues which probably point to why the uuidString value is wrong. However, I've had to make quite a few guesses.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I added crime.java but it's going to take me some time to go through and test everything else.  Should I be pulling directly out of the database class?

Comment: That's Ok. However straight waysee the issue `new Crime()` generates a random UUID which WILL in all likeliehood rarely be an ID stored so rarely, if ever, will delete delete anything. Will be here for some time so can help when needed.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  That was pretty stupid of me.  I added by database file to my original post.  I don't have a way to keep an ID along with all the other data but I'm not sure I quite understand what I am doing when it comes to creating a SQL database.  Can I just add another column with an ID and then increment it each time I add a new entry?

Comment: You already have `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, this will always be a unique identifier. So when you insert a new row it will be unique (normally 1 then 2 then 3 etc), so UUID is pretty much redundant. You can get _id s when inserting as insert returns it so `long myid = mDatabase.insert(CrimeTable.NAME, null, values);` could be of use.

Comment: I need to set a String variable to the UUID value in my database file so I can pass that into deleteCrime, right?  Where would the long myid = ... get placed?  In the database file?

Comment: @KyleG, working on updating answer, basically ignore UUID use _id, shouldn't be too long before update is done.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help.  The only thing I think that I'm still messing up is the .setOnClickListener for mDeleteButton.  How do I make sure the correct ID is then being passed to deleteCrime?

Comment: @KyleG OK updated answer, basically you add a variable myCrimeID (long) that will store the id when you add the Crime and then access this to delete it (not what you'd normally do, you'd normally access the crime from the database and get the id e.g. List crimes in a ListView say long click to delete and you get the respective id from the onItemClickListener) I guess that you'll be heading down that trail shortly.

Comment: @KyleG PS don't expect to see much though as only the underlying row will be deleted, nothing will happen on screen. I'll add some code that will allow you to see what's in the table.

Comment: thank you again so much.  I understand what everything is doing but I'm just lost on where.  I made the changes to addCrime and deleteCrime but on my main .java file I changed the onClick command to I think what you are suggesting, unless it's in the wrong place, with 

`long databaseId = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).addCrime(crime);
                CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).deleteCrime(databaseId);` but there is an error with addCrime(crime), crime cannot be resolved.

Comment: You need to declare `long databaseID;` so that it has exposure wherever it is used e.g. where I said *at the start of the fragment/activity code `long MyCrimeID;`*

Comment: I declared it as a public Long with my other declarations.  Is that correct?

Comment: @KyleG I think it needs to be coded in `CrimeListFragment.java:` as a class variable i.e. before `onCreateView` that means that it will be accessible throughout CrimeListFragment public/private just `long databaseID` would then suffice (I've never used fragments to date so I'm not familiar with them)

Comment: Then how do I set the button to actually do something?  The app didn't respond to the button at all until I added .setOnClickListener in CrimeFragment.java.  The switch in CrimeListFragment.java uses .getItemId, is that why I should be using it there?

Comment: Ok a bit of a cheat but add `mDeleteButton.setTag(databaseID)` before setting the `onCLickListener` (but after `mDeleteButton = findViewById...`) and then inside the listener have `CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).deleteCrime((long) v.getTag() );`

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  This is a really stupid question but I should delete `long databaseId = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).addCrime(crime);` right?  I deleted that and added everything else and the app shuts down and when I restart it, it occasionally duplicates the first entry.  I haven't been able to find the exact method that causes duplication, and when I deleted the app and reinstalled it, it stopped so maybe it was nothing