# Specific data retrieve from database : android

Tags: android, sql, json, database, sqlite

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_login";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_Branch = "branch";
private static final String KEY_SEM = "semester";
private static final String KEY_AMIZONE = "amizone";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            +KEY_Branch + " TEXT," +KEY_SEM + " TEXT ," +KEY_AMIZONE + " TEXT,UNIQUE" + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String name,String email, String Branch, String Semester, String Amizone, String uid, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_Branch, Branch); // uid
    values.put(KEY_SEM, Semester); // uid
    values.put(KEY_AMIZONE, Amizone); // uid
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // uid
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER  ;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("branch", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("semester", cursor.getString(7));
        user.put("amizone", cursor.getString(6));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

    return user;
}

/**
 * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void deleteUsers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
}

}
```

User_Profile.java

```
class User_Profile extends Fragment {

private TextView txtName,txtBranch,txtSem,txtAmizone;
private TextView txtEmail;
private Button btnLogout;

private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_userprofile, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("User Profile");
    txtName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtEmail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnLogout = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);


    txtName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtEmail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.email);
     txtBranch = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.branch);
     txtSem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.semester);
     txtAmizone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.amizoneid);
    btnLogout = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");
    String email = user.get("email");
    String branch = user.get("branch");
    String semester = user.get("semester");
    String amizone = user.get("amizone");

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
    txtName.setText(name);
    txtEmail.setText(email);
    txtBranch.setText(branch);
    txtAmizone.setText(amizone);
    txtSem.setText(semester);

    // Logout button click event
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logoutUser();
        }
    });
}
private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);

    db.deleteUsers();

    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(User_Profile.this.getActivity(),LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    User_Profile.this.getActivity().finish();
    Toast.makeText(User_Profile.this.getActivity(), "Logged Out Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
}
```

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnLinkToRegister;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();


            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                // login user
                checkLogin(email,password);
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user.getString("created_at");
                    String Branch = user.getString("branch");;
                    String Semester = user.getString("semester");
                    String Amizone = user.getString("amizone");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at,Branch,Semester,Amizone);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);


            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

RegisterActivity

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnRegister;
private Button btnLinkToLogin;
private EditText inputFullName;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword,semester,branch,amizoneid;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

    semester = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sem);
    branch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.branch);
    amizoneid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amizone);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String Branch = branch.getText().toString().trim();
            String Semester = semester.getText().toString().trim();
            String Amizone = amizoneid.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()&& !Branch.isEmpty() && !Semester.isEmpty()) {
                registerUser(name,email, password,Branch,Semester,Amizone);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
 * email, password) to register url
 * */
private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                          final String password,final  String Branch,final String Semester,final String Amizone) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    // Now store the user in sqlite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String Branch = user.getString("branch");
                    String Semester = user.getString("semester");
                    String Amizone = user.getString("amizone");
                    String created_at = user.getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name,email,created_at,Branch,Semester,Amizone,uid);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String tkn = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                   // Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Current token ["+tkn+"]",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Log.d("App", "Token ["+tkn+"]");

                    // Launch login activity

                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Regitering User Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("branch", Branch);
            params.put("amizone", Amizone);
            params.put("semester", Semester);
            params.put("password", password);


            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Error : In the User_Profile , not able to retrieve user specific data from the SQl database , only the email and name is showing , other details are blank

Details for fetching data from SQldatabase : D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=test@test.com, name=Priyansh, semester=, created_at=2017-08-25 18:09:06, uid=59a067c2185e95.56562559, branch=, amizone=}

Comment: Is it by anychance something do with **uid** and **branch** not being index **4** and **3** respectively, but **3** and **4**? I would suggest changing your code from (***as one example of the multiple occurrences***) using `user.put("uid", cursor.getString(4));` i.e. a hard coded index, to using `user.put("uid", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_UID)));` i.e. index is determined according to column name.

Comment: after applying changes this is coming , details are replaced

D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=test@test.com, name=Priyansh, semester=2017-08-25 18:09:06, created_at=, uid=, branch=59a067c2185e95.56562559, amizone=}

Comment: @MikeT send ur email or fb id , wanna discuss

Comment: priyansh.mishra19@gmail.com my id

Comment: What happens if you change `cursor.moveToFirst();` to `cursor.moveToLast` ? (PS, using  `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` could replace `cursor.moveToFirst();     if (cursor.getCCount() > 0) {`. You could have at look at [Can database entries added from items be deleted with button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722118/can-database-entries-added-from-items-be-deleted-with-button/45722306#45722306), at the bottom is a method **`showAll`** that will list the data for all columns. I suspect that the database may not have been populated properly.

Comment: yes , i think so not populated properly , tell ur email want to discuss ! @MikeT